# Provider in ListView not getting disposed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-listview

I have `ListView` with a list (`values`) containing ~600 objects:

```dart
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: values.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<DatabaseRepository,
              AlbumViewModel>(
            initialBuilder: (context) => AlbumViewModel(album: values[index]),
            builder: (context, dbRepo, vm) => vm..databaseRepository = dbRepo,
            child: const AlbumEntryView(),
          );
```

With the according `AlbumEntryView`

```dart
class AlbumEntryView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AlbumEntryView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _flagIconButton(AlbumViewModel model) {
    IconData icon = model.album.flagged ? Icons.flag : Icons.outlined_flag;
    return IconButton(icon: Icon(icon), onPressed: () => model.toggleFlagged());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AlbumViewModel model = Provider.of(context);
    return ListTile(
        title: Text(model.album.title),
        trailing: _flagIconButton(model),;
  }
```

I checked the memory in my app for the **amount of** `ChangeNofifierProxyProvider` objects and it keeps increasing when I scroll through the list (it holds the `AlbumEntryView` object).

As far as I know, the `ListView` releases widgets when they are not in the viewPort and the Provider is getting disposed when it's not in the view hierarchy anymore. **Does that mean, that the list items are not getting disposed/reused resulting the objects to grow in the memory view or did I misunderstand something?** If so, how can I properly use the provider as a list item without facing the issue of a potential leak of the app?

Comment: I've just tested and they _are_ disposed. Either you have a widget in the tree that asks for the tree to not be destroyed (see KeepAlive), or it's properly disposed and misinterpreted the devtool.

Comment: Thank you for testing this out. So, in your end the amount of `ChangeNofifierProxyProvider` objects does not increase? My memory does gets cleaned up properly, too, but the number of objects don't get smaller.